# The jquery wrap function with anchor tag not working in IE8

Tags: jquery

This http://jsfiddle.net/jquerybyexample/f9p6C/ does not work for me in IE8. I am trying to do something similar in my code. Any thoughts?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you are missing greater sign after the opening a tag

before

```
currentImage.wrap("<a target='_blank' href='" + currentImage.attr("src") + "'</a>");
```

after

```
currentImage.wrap("<a target='_blank' href='" + currentImage.attr("src") + "'></a>");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/f9p6C/13/

Comment: And also because IE browsers actually refuse to run your incorrectly written code, as opposed to most other browsers try to make it work anyway. In cases like this, I wonder if it's even a good thing...